# Command/Control keys are split on PC keyboard with Mac

Tags: keyboard

No matter how many combinations I try in Modifier Keys, unfortunately the control/command keys split responsibilities.

For example:

Control x, c, v all work fine, but Control z, t, r don't work - instead i have to use Command z, t, r.

Is there a way to have one of these buttons for all shortcuts? I tried changing Modifier Keys to use Command for all shortcuts but my Mac would not respect it. Also tried Karabiner. FYI I'm using a Razer keyboard.

TIA

edit: updated w/ image and scenarios -

[image: current settings on my mac w/ razer keyboad]

the above settings allows the following:

1) in TextEdit on my mac, the following commands work:
ctrl x, c, v all works. but ctrl a, z do not work. in order to do ctrl a, z , i have to do windows key + a, z

2) in chrome, i have to do windows t, r in order to open new tab or reload. in chrome url area - i can only do windows + z, x, c, v, a (ctrl doesnt work with any of these despite working partially in TextEdit!!)

3) in gmail - windows a, z works. and ctrl x, c, v works. !

I tried multiple combinations in modifier keys section for keyboard but no matter what combination i try, the commands always split b/w ctrl and windows key. i also tried Karabiner using every variation under the sun but to no avail.

Is a computer reset my only option? Brand new mac been using for 1 month. :/

Comment: That doesn't sound normal. What is the application where this is happening? Can you take a screenshot of the top menu items related to this issue? Or you could just list what the menu items says about the shortcuts. Also is it just one application or are the shortcuts wonky like that everywhere?

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. i have updated my original post w/ image and additional information. thanks again

Comment: If you look at the menubar at the top, what does it say the shortcuts are for these commands? I'm trying to confirm the source of this. If the menu items list these shortcuts with some of them being ctrl and some of them being cmd, it might be an OS level change. If all of these commands say cmd+whatever, then it's likely something else. All of these commands by default use Cmd. You could also try booting to safe mode, which disables all third party apps so you could see if they affect it. And perhaps to make a new user, because that should reset all the settings that have been changed.

Comment: A bit repetitive, but; something has to be changing some of your shortcuts to use ctrl. My primary suspect is https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac – If the top menu items say some of the shortcuts use ctrl, then it's likely this. Though I'm not sure how that could've accidentally happened. My next suspect is third party apps. If all top menu items say they should use Cmd, then it's likely a third party app... That's what I'm thinking right now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I think you are right. I looked at Chrome and clicked edit in the top menu, and sure enough the commands are split: ⌘Z ^X ^C ^V ⌘T ⌘N ⌘R ⌘A. I checked in a few other apps and the are also split. Looks like we might have found a solution! - Is there a way to change this system-wide? Ideally to have everything using the control button?

Comment: For better or for worse, you could try to overwrite the wonky shortcuts using the OS's own keyboard shortcuts (link in my last comment). Just make sure Karabiner is not trying to do something else in the background (or anything else). — Here's an example: **1.** Normally it's [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOrBm.png) **2.** But I can go and change it [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp7RC.png). Note that I changed it under `App Shortcuts` and chose to change it in: `All Applications`. **3.** And then the new shortcut shows up in the [menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUhKI.png).

Comment: Okay thanks! I have updated the shortcuts in All Applications using the ctrl key. This seems to have fixed it, thank you! Just curious why you say 'for better or for worse' - is there a lurking issue which might reappear in the future? Any reason why these shortcuts i just added won't stay permanent?

Comment: Well the default modifier key for these shortcuts you mentioned is cmd, so if something changed some of them to control and you're now overwriting those with new shortcuts... It's more of a band-aid, than a fix for the underlying issue. I'm spit balling, but it could be the thing that changed them was a third party application that you don't use often and the next time you do, it could just override these changes. But I mean the worst that could happen is exactly that. Then you'd have to do this again.

Comment: okay thank you. and one more question if you dont mind - i just realized that for example on this page if i hit ctrl+a then it highlights the whole page, but if i click inside of this very text box and hit ctrl+a then it doesn't select all text. the same thing happens in Slack and within gmail.

Comment: It seems to be related to web textareas and the control key. The menu command still works if you click it in the menu. Something about `ctrl` that they just don't seem to like. — The only fix that comes to mind is to undo the OS shortcut change and use a 3rd party application to trigger `cmd+a` when `ctrl+a` is pressed. I used [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) to do this and it worked. I'm not sure how to do it with Karabiner. I haven't used it since it was rewritten from scratch. There are many applications that can do it, but the only ones that come to mind are paid applications.

Comment: I looked up how Karabiner Elements does it nowadays. Basically the same as how it used to, except it's now controlled by a JSON file as opposed to an XML file. I made you a file by modifying the `PC-style modifiers` preset (added `Ctrl+A → Cmd+A` at the end): https://pastebin.com/6Ag4kFJC — Save it as `Karabiner Elements - PC style modifiers.json` and put it at `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications`. More documentation [here](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html#from-event-definition-examples). The file has other modifications, but you don't have to enable them all.

Comment: oh great, thank you for sending that over!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that <Ctrl> on a "PC" keyboard is the same as <CTRL> on a Mac keyboard.  Normally on a Mac you would need to use <Command>-C for copy, not <CTRL>-C.

Note that on a PC keynote <Alt> and <Command> keys are normally reversed. Maybe this is what you are trying to fix via the Modifier keys in the keyboard control panel?

Below is the mappings hatI have for his exact configuration:
[image: <CTRL>]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my original question w/ scenarios - basically no matter what combination i try in modifier keys, it always splits between ctrl and windows key